# Does Iphone receive all push notification after net connection is back

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am developing an application with push notification.

When the receiver is not connected to WIFI/internet while the sender is sending  messages, does the receiver receive all of the sent messages when the receiver reconnects to the internet?

Comment: Very likely, but Apple made no guarantee on push notification. They shouldn't be used as primary method for sending critical information.

Comment: No reciver receive all messages when connected back to internet because reciever does't send repeat message

Comment: i checked ur answer.the user receives recent notification only.

Comment: if a user sends 4 messages in a row the 4th message only received by receiver

Answer (score 9):

There is a queue that will be sent to the user once he/she gets an internet access. However if the user is without internet for a "*long time*" there is no guarantee that the notification will be sent/recveived.

The Apple documentation is very vague on what amount of time that is considered *long time*. (See [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html))

> Apple Push Notification service includes a default Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function.
>
> If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered to the device when it becomes available.
>
> Only one recent notification for a particular application is stored. If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as coalescing notifications.
>
> **If the device remains offline for a long time, any notifications that were being stored for it are discarded.**

However I've heard that the APNS will try to resend the notification for approximately 25-30 days. However there is no official documentation supporting this!

Comment: You should probably mention the expiry parameter, which controls the amount of time the notification is stored : `Expiry: A fixed UNIX epoch date expressed in seconds (UTC) that identifies when the notification is no longer valid and can be discarded. The expiry value uses network byte order (big endian). If the expiry value is positive, APNs tries to deliver the notification at least once. Specify zero (or a value less than zero) to request that APNs not store the notification at all.`

Answer (score 1):

No by APNS and other fire base its not possible to get all notification. 
we can take only the last notification send by the application .

another possible solution is to save in database and write one scheduler to fire notification after period of time limit.

Answer (score 0):

When the device is connecting to APNs over WiFi ensure that no firewalls are blocking inbound and outbound TCP packets over port 5223.
5223 port communicate with APNS . and see following are other solution for it.

TCP port 5223 to communicate with APNs.
TCP port 2195 to send notifications to APNs.
TCP port 2196 for the APNs feedback service.
TCP port 443 is required during device activation, and afterwards for fallback (on Wi-Fi only) if devices can't reach APNs on port 5223.
Check with your network administrator to make sure that the ports are accessible.